# Logging Graph SDK calls to Application Insights (in Azure Function)

Tags: logging, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm calling the Graph API (MS Graph .NET SDK) in my Azure Function, and want to see those calls in Application Insights. However, they don't seem to ever get logged.

Other logging *does* show up as expected.

My logging configuration is as such:

```json
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "Default": "Trace",
      "Host": "Warning",
      "System.Net.Http.HttpClient": "Trace"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingExcludedTypes": "Request",
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true
      }
    }
  },
```

I tried removing `logLevel` completely, or only setting `Default: trace`, but nothing seems to help.

Is there something special needed in the Graph SQK's HttpClient perhaps?

For completeness:

The GraphSDK client is registered by:

```cs
services
    .AddSingleton<IGraphServiceClient>(provider =>
    {
        var tokenProvider = provider.GetRequiredService<IAccessTokenProvider>();

        var authenticationProvider = new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async request =>
        {
            request
                .Headers
                .Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "token...");
        });

        return new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);
    });
```

And I use the client as:

```cs
public class MyFunc {
    private readonly IGraphServiceClient _client;
    public MyFunc(IGraphServiceClient client) { _client = client; }

    public async Task Run() {
        var groups = await _client.Groups.Request().Get();
    }
}
```

Comment: do you check them in the `dependencies table` of application insights logs?

Comment: Yes you need to check at the dependencies table of the app insights?

Comment: The dependencies are logged indeed, but I would like to see the Trace/Debug/Information logs as well, which should be possible using the System.Net.Http.* log category.

Answer (score 0):

These operations should be marked as dependency.

Please go to azure portal -> application insights -> Logs ->in the `dependencies` table, and check if the logs are there.

Comment: The dependencies are logged indeed, but I would like to see the Trace/Debug/Information logs as well, which should be possible using the System.Net.Http.* log category.